Failed: failed to start .snap.network-manager.networkmanager.service
I see this on my black display when Ubuntu 24.04LTS crashes to the black screen and requires logging back in or rebooting...what does it mean and how do I fix it... or does it need fixing?

problem with network manager is that it kills my PCI WiFi upon resume from sleep/suspend mode (did it back with 20.04LTS a lot), but with the current 24.04LTS using the 5.15.0-105-generic kernel, this problem has gone away - goes in and out of sleep mode and I still have WiFi… maybe having network manager failing is a GOOD THING?!?
